# copy data to the input of FFTW waste a lot of time?

Tags: fftw

I hava a array A of 512*1024*127(rho,column page),and I want to do 2D FFT to every page,
when I create a FFTW plane,for example:

```
fftwf_plan mFFTPalen = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(1024, 512, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I want to use this plane to finish all the 2D ffts, that is 127 times 2D fft,
I have to copy the data into the "in" array 127 times,
and  copy the fft result from the "out" array 127 times,
I think it is a waste of time,

```
for(int plane=0; plane<127; plane++)
{
memcpy(in, A[plane*512*1024], sizeof(float)*512*1024);
fftwf_execute(mFFTPalen);
memcpy(complexData,out,sizeof(float)*513*512*2);
}
```

Can anyone tell me am I do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fftwf_plan_many_dft` from the [Advanced Interface](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) to save all this copying. Only do this though if you are certain that you have a performance problem, otherwise it's just a waste of effort.